# Windows 8 Asus laptop: Screen Brightness is auto-adjusting despite being disabled

Tags: windows-8, laptop, display, brightness, asus-laptop

I'm not sure if this is a problem being caused by Windows 8, the asus power-management programs, or what. Whenever my screen is displaying something darker, specifically the Steam client or in games/movies/other media, the screen dims, and when i go back to a brighter program like skype or firefox, it brightens.

I have disabled adaptive brightness multiple times, and it claims to be off. My power plan should have the screen remaining at 100% brightness all the time, and it doesn't put itself to sleep or anything. It's only when my screen attempts to display darker colors, it also dims.

It's becoming a problem in games with bright flashes because the entire screen will brighten and dim back and forth repeatedly.

Is there a setting I have missed?

Answer (score -1):

Disable the adaptive brightness in the advanced settings, display section in the power mode settings