# Brightness changes while "Adaptive Brightness" is disabled in Windows 8.1/10 with Intel HD Graphics

Tags: windows-10, laptop, windows-8.1, intel-graphics, brightness

The brightness changes with the colors displayed on the screen on my Lenovo Thinkpads with Intel HD Graphics. Light colors make the screen brighter, dark make it darker. Same behavior in Windows 8.1 and 10.

The "adaptive brightness" feature in Windows is disabled.

Comment: In case you come here from google and own an x240: http://superuser.com/questions/743915/screen-brightness-changes-depending-on-screen-contents-how-do-i-turn-it-off/743923#743923

Comment: In case you have a Surface 4: https://mikebattistablog.wordpress.com/2016/05/27/disable-intel-dpst-on-sp4/

Comment: In AMD, go to Catalyst Control Center > Power > PowerPlay and uncheck "Enable Vari-Bright"

Comment: There is another trick that worked for me https://superuser.com/a/1565785/43789

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just found a suggestion that solved my problem [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-do-you-completely-disable-adaptive-brightness/b0161873-4ebb-4070-bdad-fdcc01f17e16?auth=1).

It is the Intel "Display Power Saving Technology" that is to blame.

Disable it like so:

1. Launch "Intel HD Graphics Control Panel" by right clicking and selecting "Graphics Properties..." from your Intel HD Graphics tray icon
2. Click Power
3. Choose "On battery"
4. Select "Disable" for Display Power Saving Technology
5. Click Apply

[image: Intel HD Graphics Control Panel example]

Comment: My charger was connecting and disconnecting repeatedly because it was overheating (it has a safety feature to turn off at a certain temperature). This didn't occur to me for half an hour. Unlikely, but worth noting.

Comment: Make sure to restart your computer to fully apply the changes

Comment: I'm running HP Envy and everything I've tried worked only for a short time, until restart or wake up. The only solution was to unplug power cable and plug it again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was figuring out the issue from last week.

Comment: This works until the computer goes to sleep. After a wake from sleep, the colors/brightness starts changing again.

Comment: This option is randomly ignored most of the time. HD Graphics control panel has had numerous bugs for years It doesn't look like they are going to fix them. You have to install their generic driver (manually or with Intel® Driver & Support Assistant) - that will fix all the problems.

Comment: the "Intel HD Graphics Control Center" app is no longer maintained, Intel however did publish a replacement app called "Intel Graphics Command Center" and turning off "Display Power Savings" (System -> Power -> Battery) did the trick and never reverted back afterwards.

Comment: Help, my latest Intel HD Graphic Control Panel doesn't comes with "Plugged In" and "On Battery" on the left tabs anymore T-T

Answer (score 37):

Even after changing the "power" options in the "Intel HD graphics control panel" the brightness kept adapting to the image brightness/darkness.

So did some research and found a solution through editing the registry.

instructions:

1. press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
2. type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Brighten Movie` and change `ProcAmpBrightness` to `0`
4. also navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Darken Movie` and change `ProcAmpBrightness` to `0`

This should solve the problem.

Comment: These reg. values are not in my registry..?

Comment: do you have to restart? this is still not working.

Comment: For me it works after reboot

Comment: You are a total genius! There is another way to do this. I believe you can change the brightness in brighten and darken video from the Intel graphics properties interface -> Profiles -> selecting the aforementioned profiles  and saving the changes after loading the profile and resetting the brightness.

Comment: Thank, this works. Either reboot, or if you have two display adapters in your computer, disable and enable intel HD graphics for the modifications to take effect.

Comment: This is the only solution which works after attempted all the methods available on the internet. This is probably the best solution in human history +1.

Comment: It's odd that this affects the adaptive brightness or Display Power Saving Technology, as wouldn't these two registry items just control the relative brightness of the two respective video profiles under Graphics Options -> Profiles in the desktop context menu?

Comment: Thanks for this, seems to have fixed my problem too when everything else didn't.

Answer (score 6):

So i just fixed this problem temporarily.
What i did is i went to Device Manager, then went to Display adapters.

**Now i have 2 graphics cards in my system, one is an integrated Intel HD4000 and the second is a Geforce GT740M so i dont know if this will work on systems with 1 graphics card.**

After this just disable and enable your integrated graphics card and it should fix it.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Somehow my display defaulted to Intel graphics when I have AMD Radeon

Comment: this is the only option that helped me

Answer (score 2):

I've looked around the web and there appear to be several possible causes and solutions to this problem depending on your Windows version and hardware. Here's a compilation of how to turn off adaptive brightness.

1. Go to **Power Options** > Display > Enable Adaptive Brightness > Set it to Off in both places

[image]

2. Go to **AMD Catalyst Control Center** > Power > PowerPlay > Uncheck the "Enable Vari-Bright" box

[image]

3. Go to the **Intel Media and Graphics Control Panel** > Power > Disable Intel Power Saving Technology

[image]

4. Go to **Services** > Disable the Adapative Brightness service

[image]

5. In **regedit:**

   Go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Brighten Movie** and change ProcAmpBrightness to 0

   Go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Darken Movie** and change ProcAmpBrightness to 0

Comment: This is probably a great solution for AMD graphics, but this topic is for the Intel HD Graphics. I suggest you add a new question/topic for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many of these fixes and nothing worked.  I was finally able to beat this problem though.  I have an i7 processor with integrated HD graphics but also have an nVidia card as well.  During Windows 10 setup  (or maybe before) my integrated HD card was disabled in my BIOS.  I had to enable the integrated HD graphics and then in Windows install the newest HD graphic drivers.  After the drivers installed all my tweaking around in the power options screen actually did something. Your mileage may vary but I think enabling the disabled integrated video chip in the BIOS and installing the proper drivers is what was missing. At least for me.

Comment: You didn't specify what you tweaked. You explained how you solved the problem, but could you reproduce the steps you took to solve the problem? If you could find out some other information on what you changed, you should update your answer.

Comment: This topic is for the Intel HD Graphics. I suggest you add a new question/topic for this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Everything here didn't help and in the end the problem was in the monitor itself - it is a mag monitor went into the monitor's settings (the physical menu button on monitor) and go into color and change DCR mode to off

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and also tried all of those fixes and nothing worked till now.
I use a secondary monitor for my laptop and was able to fix the problem when I disconnected the secondary monitor, restarted the power plan from the advance power setting ("restore plan defaults"), then restarting my laptop and after that changing the adaptive brightness to off. 
It works just fine now.

Answer (score -3):

Here's the easy way I found: [Adaptive Brightness Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BxNU.png)

[image]

Comment: OP stated that he already had adaptive brightness turned off

Answer (score -4):

This happened to me also.  I tried all of the other solutions but none worked. Then I noticed that my desktop background was not my usual.

I right-clicked on the desktop, chose "Personalize" and in the Background slot, I chose "Picture" and clicked on the picture I wanted.  The problem went away.