# Brightness changes even with auto bright off Surface 6

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics

I'm having a problem like the title says, while using my PC I can notice how it starts changing the screen brightness in a very annoying way, it's like it goes step by step changing it and it is really annoying. I have already disabled the auto brightness but got no luck. I also tried going into `regedit` and when I'm trying to go to this path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Brighten
```

I don't see that level, I have only until `igfxcui`. Could anyone please help me?

[image]

Comment: Laptop? Have you looked at power management settings?

Comment: @davidgo yes I have, and nope, still the same issue, i found an old article in here but it didnt work for me, thats why i asked this, the article is this one https://superuser.com/questions/994443/brightness-changes-while-adaptive-brightness-is-disabled-in-windows-8-1-10-wit

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to go to startup and turn off surface control brightness app, then restart.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Exactly what steps should the user take?