# My computer's display goes bright and dark automatically

Tags: windows-10, display, brightness, display-settings

I have a Windows 10 PC but recently I realised that when I look at something bright my screen turns its brightness down but when I look at something dark my brightness goes bright? I don't know I'm **confused...** but it really makes me angry... It's like an automatic brightness thing but I don't know whether is coming from my monitor or my computer's settings. Any help is appreciated! ( It's a desktop not a laptop by the way and also I have a TV Monitor )

Comment: Is it a laptop or a desktop monitor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brightness changes while "Adaptive Brightness" is disabled in Windows 8.1/10 with Intel HD Graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/994443/brightness-changes-while-adaptive-brightness-is-disabled-in-windows-8-1-10-wit)

Comment: Are you using nightlight?  https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/enable-windows-10-night-light

Comment: @Lumberjack Not using nightlight

Comment: @grawity edited post, desktop TV monitor

Comment: "TV monitor" might be a clue – many TVs actually have automatic content-based brightness adjustment.

Comment: Monitor model is LG M2362D V3.19.0

Comment: @mael' I don't think it's the same post since I don't have an adaptive brightness setting on my power options and I have a desktop pc

Comment: did you read the answer to that question, though?

Comment: Check if you could find the setting below:go to Settings  > System > Display. Under Brightness and color, look for the Change brightness automatically when lighting changes

Comment: @mael' Yes, I did read it but didn't work