# My laptop screen dims when a dark image is shown onscreen

Tags: windows-10, laptop, brightness, backlight

I have a Windows 10 Dell XPS 15 (9530) laptop which is working fine except for the fact that ***when plugged in*** (not on battery) the screen dims whenever I view a dark **image/content on the screen**.

Note that the screen brightness does not change when ambient lighting changes in the room (I already turned off adaptive brightness from the Control Panel). The issue is that it changes when I am viewing dark contents/images (e.g. viewing a nighttime photo, or visiting a website with a dark background) on the screen. This is a big issue for me as I do a lot of video and photo editing and I need the screen brightness to remain the same at all times.

I seem to be having a similar issue as highlighted in this post:

[Screen Brightness Changes Depending on Screen Contents - how do i turn it off?](https://superuser.com/questions/743915/screen-brightness-changes-depending-on-screen-contents-how-do-i-turn-it-off?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, those solutions don't work for me (including turning Display Power Saving Technology off from within the Intel Graphics Properties). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have "DELL Premier Color" or "DELL True Color" installed?

Comment: Nope, I don't...

Comment: I think the term to use for narrowing your search is "Dynamic Backlight Control" or "DBC." it is deifferent than the windows powercfg setting. Dell has firmware updates for other XPS models ( http://www.dell.com/support/article/is/en/isbsdt1/sln304876/xps-9343--9350--9360-and-9365-2-in-1-lcd-brightness-issues?lang=en ). Doesn't look like it is exposed for the 9530, but perhaps you can dig up something. Post and accept your answer if you solve it.

Comment: it might be exposed via either gpu driver interface...

Comment: No problem, thanks for following up with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved the issue by following this link and downloading all firmware updates for my laptop model:

http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/product-support/product/xps-15-9530/drivers

Answer (score 0):

On Dell Vostro 5490 with Windows 10, I solved the problem by disabling "Eco Power" in the Video settings and also setting the screen brightness on Battery power to 100%. (Screenshot is from an Inspiron, but Bios screen is the same on my Vostro).

[Dell Bios Video settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGBDs.jpg)

I found information online about doing this change in Windows settings, but the described settings were missing on my machine even after updating the Graphics (Intel + Nvidia) drivers and the Bios. For example, in Edit Power Plan -> advanced settings, under Display, I only have the option "Turn off display after".